# Javascript equivalent of C# code

Tags: javascript, c#

I can't find the JavaScript equivalent of this C# code anywhere.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I'm trying to force Tls via JavaScript

Comment: You won't find an equivalent because JavaScript doesn't work against the .NET Framework Base Class Library. There is only one word in your code that is actually C#, `true` and that is the same in JavaScript. Everything else is using a CLR object.

Comment: Javascript on what platform?

Comment: It really would help if you explained why you think you need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but you could do something along these lines to enforce an agent to use particular security.

```
var protocol = require('https');
var configuration = {
     hostname: '',
     port: 443,
     path: '',
     method: '',
     secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
}

protocol.request(configuration, context => {
   // Request information such as body.  
});
```

Not sure that is your intent though, would need more information.